# Evaluating $\int \frac {\sin x}{1+x^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you integrate this? Tried different substitution already but I failed:

$$\int \dfrac {\sin x}{1+x^2}~dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Found this somewhere:

integral $\int \dfrac{sin x}{1+x^2} dx = ((e^2-1) Ci(i-x)+(e^2-1) Ci(x+i)+i (1+e^2) (Si(i-x)+Si(x+i)))/(4 e)+constant$

Note that Ci(x) and Si(x) are the cosine and sine integrals respectively.

Comment: This comes, perhaps, from WA, but without some explanation I think it may hardly help.

Comment: Perhaps this is copy-paste.